# Nvidia graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have troubles with NvidiaGraphicCard on Linux Mint . So at first I have downloaded the cuda libs for Linux. Drivers are from the cuda **NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.39.run** All have installed but I have this:
Of course

```
$glxgears
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

DeviceQuesry from CUDA:

```
 deviceQuery
    ./deviceQuery Starting...

     CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

    Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

    Device 0: "GeForce GTX 960M"
      CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
      CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
      Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147352576 bytes)
      ( 5) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     640 CUDA Cores
      GPU Max Clock rate:                            1176 MHz (1.18 GHz)
      Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
      Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
      L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
      Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
      Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
      Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
      Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
      Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
      Total number of registers available per block: 65536
      Warp size:                                     32
      Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
      Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
      Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
      Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
      Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
      Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
      Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
      Run time limit on kernels:                     No
      Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
      Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
      Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
      Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
      Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
      Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
      Compute Mode:
         < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

    deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 960M
    Result = PASS
```

nvidia-smi:

```
Mon Oct 12 15:07:58 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.39     Driver Version: 352.39         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      7MiB /  2047MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

lspci

```
filip@filip-laptop /usr/local/cuda-7.5/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery $ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1612] (rev 0a) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1138]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1138]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
```

nvidia-setting :

```
You do not appear to be usin NVIDIA X driver....
```

running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` doesn't work.

So any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but this site is about Ubuntu and the official Ubuntu family only - I guess the goal is to make a repository of good questions and answers that are, specifically, about Ubuntu. I add that Ubuntu is special simply because of its large comunity/ecosystem. However, you'll probably be asked to post your question elsewhere. I've had great luck on their forums which you can find here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/

Answer (score 4):

As you are using very new GPU hardware, it is recommended to use the very latest stable drivers.
Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting GTX960 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.
Before you install new drivers uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from NVIDIA short-lived branch by executing
(as you have a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install NVIDIA Optimus support as well) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

Comment: Im purging cuda and nvidia setting now. So after instalation i will give a comment.

Comment: Should I install  bumblebee bumblebee first or driver?

Comment: I had to install nvidia-settings. And when I want to switch to NVIDIA i have :
ERROR " " nothing. Youst ERROR

Comment: so i should purge the nvidia-prime and install bumblebee?>

Comment: Ofcourse I did something additionaly;pppp I have installed bumblee. So I will remove it and I will write you what is going now

Comment: Yep it's working. Now lets install CUDA

Comment: I have tried everythin I know. And it doesn't work for CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

After CUDA instalation I have the same problem. I have ommit the CUDA NVIDIA Driver Installation, in first, then in other approach I have installed that driver, but non of those Drivers works.

If I install the nvidia_355 the OpenGL works, but CUDA doesn't.
In other hand If I install the driver from CUDA the OpenGL does'nt work and CUDA does.

...